# jQuery select2 tags without default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I design input box for insert tags using select2 plugin like this :

HTML :

```
<input id="tags" class="text-input form-control"  type="text" name="tags" size="24"  placeholder="tags" >
```

JS:(in docs)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tags").select2({
    tags: ["red", "green", "blue"],
    maximumInputLength: 10
    });
});
```

this worked for me and show drop down for default `red, green,blue`. but i need to remove tags from default drop down. my mean is i design my input without default tags in dropdwon.

how do create this ?

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xra9k/276/)

Comment: *i need to remove tagsfrom default drop down* -- Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're tring to accomplish is user-defined, multiple select, with no defaults, you can try the following:

```
$('#tagSelect').select2({
    multiple: true, 
    tags: [], 
    formatNoMatches: null,
    maximumInputLength: 10
});
```

Here's an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/aqftozLv/).